# Replacing all negative values from a dataset

Tags: r, replace, stata, missing-data

I have a `dataframe` with mixed data ranging from variables(or columns) with numerical values to variables(or columns) with factors.

I would like to use the following piece of code in R to replace all negative values with NA and subsequently remove the entire variable if more than 99% of observations for that variable are NA.

The first part should make sure there is no problem when encountering strings.
Would it be possible to simply start with:

```
mydata$v1[mydata$v1<0] <- NA
```

But then not specific for `v1` and only if the observation is not a string ?

Follow up:
This is how far I got with the explanation provided by @stas g. It does however not seem like any variable was dropped from the df.

```
#mixed data
df <- data.frame(WVS_Longitudinal_1981_2014_R_v2015_04_18)
dat <- df[,sapply(df, function(x) {class(x)== "numeric" | class(x) == 
"integer"})]

foo <- function(dat, p){ 
  ind <- colSums(is.na(dat))/nrow(dat)
  dat[dat < 0] <- NA
  dat[, ind < p]
}

#process numeric part of the data separately
ii <- sapply(df, class) == "numeric" | sapply(df, class) == "integer"
dat.num <- foo(as.matrix(df[, ii]), 0.99)
#then stick the two parts back together again
WVS <- data.frame(df[, !ii], dat.num)
```

Comment: you need to provide a minimal reproducible example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This approach: [Solution by YOLO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51377120/removing-negative-values-when-variable-is-an-atomic-vector/51379527?noredirect=1#comment89970978_51379527) suggested by @YOLO finally solved the issue:

```
cleanFun <- function(df){

    # set negative values as NA
    df[df < 0] <- NA

    # faster, vectorized solution
    # select numeric columns
    num_cols <- names(df)[sapply(df, is.numeric)]

    # get name of columns with 99% or more NA values
    col_to_remove <- names(df)[colMeans(is.na(df[num_cols]))>=0.99]

    # drop those columns
    return (df[setdiff(colnames(df),col_to_remove)])
}

your_df <- cleanFun(your_df)
```

Answer (score 1):

impossible to know exactly how to help you without a minimal reproducible example, but assuming you have a sample data below:

```
#matrix of random normal observations, 20 samples, 5 variables
dat <- matrix(rnorm(100), nrow = 20)
#if entry is negative, replace with 'NA'
dat[dat < 0] <- NA

#threshold for dropping a variable
p <- 0.99
#check how many NAs in each column (proportionally)
ind <- colSums(is.na(dat))/nrow(dat)
#only keep columns where threshold is not exceded
dat <- dat[, ind < p]
```

if you have non-numeric variables and you are dealing with a `data.frame` you could do something like this (assuming you don't care about order of columns):

```
#generate mixed data
dat <- matrix(rnorm(100), nrow = 20) #20 * 50 numeric numbers
df <- data.frame(letters[1 : 20], dat) #combined with one character column 


foo <- function(dat, p){ 
  ind <- colSums(is.na(dat))/nrow(dat)
  dat[dat < 0] <- NA
  dat[, ind < p]
}

#process numeric part of the data separately
ii <- sapply(df, class) == "numeric" #ind of numeric columns
dat.num <- foo(as.matrix(df[, ii]), 0.99) #feed numeric part of data to foo
#then stick the two partw back together again
data.frame(df[, !ii], dat.num)
```

Comment: Thank you for answering despite the problems with my question. I'm trying to improve it at the moment. 

Does R(studio) not mind that some variables will be strings etcetera?

Comment: depends what you mean by that. if some of your variables are not numeric, your data will be stored in a `data.frame` rather than a matrix as in my answer

Comment: Thank you for your help! I will go through it again in the morning.

Comment: My apologies, it has been a while since I have had the time to look into this. I am trying to apply your code to my data. I assume that if I have a dataset I do not generate data, but I replace `dat` with the name of my dataset (everywhere in your code). What I am still confused about is the purpose of `df <- data.frame(letters[1 : 20], dat)`. Could you perhaps explain?

Comment: @TomKisters this just creates a non-numeric column (full of letters of the alphabet from the 1st to the 20th), to create an example of a data.frame that has more than just numeric data

Comment: Okay, I think I am beginning to understand. I am however still a bit confused about `foo`. Does the `dat` used in `foo` refer to the `dat` from the first paragraph? Or is it just a completely separate function?

If it does refer to the first paragraph it appears to make use of the matrix (which only holds numbers). For my own dataset I do however not know which columns only have numbers. Even though the last paragraph of the code does check whether the class of the dataframe is "numeric", I guess I would have to apply that check to my dataframe to get the matrix?

Comment: @TomKisters `dat` in function `foo` is just an argument name and has nothing to do with the `dat` matrix at the beginning (you should read about how to write basic functions in R, really). it could have as well been called `x`. as you can see, i create an index of numeric columns and then pass just the numeric part of the data `df` to foo, then stick the output and non-numeric columns back together.